# Python read_excel automatically deletes time data

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

```
for y in range(2010, 2021):
    print(y)
    o3file = glob('/home/hh/Air/'+ str(y) + '/*.xlsx')
    print(len(o3file), o3file)
    for m in o3file:
        fileread = pd.read_excel(m, engine='openpyxl')
        monthlyo3 = pd.DataFrame(fileread)
        monthlyo3['plc'] = monthlyo3['plc'].map(lambda r : str(r)[0:2])
        try:
            monthlyo3['date'] = pd.to_datetime(monthlyo3['date'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d%H')
        except:
            monthlyo3['date'] = monthlyo3['date'].map(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(str(x)[:-2] + '00', format='%Y%m%d%H') + timedelta(hours=24))               
        print(monthlyo3.columns.tolist())
        allall = allall.append(monthlyo3[['date','plc','NO2', 'O3']], ignore_index=False)
```

Original data has a data format of 2010010100 which contains a time info.
However if I read files, I get 2010-01-01, even for original dataframes.

I tried dtype=str, but it didn't work.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: How is the column handled in Excel, is it type date/time there already? Text? Number?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, they're in text format in Excel.

Comment: And what is the data type and content of `monthlyo3['plc']` after you load excel to df, before doing anything with the column?

Comment: Just strings which contain place names.

Comment: can you add an example to the question? I'm still having difficulties understanding the issue

Comment: I don't know why, but somehow it's working well now. Still, thank you for having 
 interest for my question.